# Copied the red band of the RGB TIFF file with GDAL in C++

Tags: gdal, c++, visual-studio

I'm a rookie in GDAL and C++. I tried to copy the red band of the RGB tif file with Create() and GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(). I got the right size of my new tif file, but all the value of the new image is 128. I tried to check the value while it run, and I'm sure they have the same value in the red band of the RGB TIFF file. I guessed there is something wrong in the GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(). However, I still have no idea after checking the document.

This project need to run with the Visual Studio 2008 on Win10, so I used the version 2.2.3 of GDAL.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h" //for CPLMalloc()
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
//Register GDAL
 GDALAllRegister();

//image file input_file
const char* input = "C:\\Users\\GOLiF\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\GDAL_223\\GDAL_223\\94212060_20190924_109EMAP.tif";
const char* output = "C:\\Users\\GOLiF\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\GDAL_223\\GDAL_223\\test.tif";

GDALDataset *pOldDS, *pNewDS ;
GDALDriver *pDriverTiff ;
int nRows, nCols ;
double transform[6] ;
double noData ;

pOldDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen( input, GA_ReadOnly ) ;

nRows = pOldDS ->GetRasterBand(1) ->GetYSize() ;
nCols = pOldDS ->GetRasterBand(1) ->GetXSize() ;
noData = pOldDS ->GetRasterBand(1) ->GetNoDataValue() ;
pOldDS ->GetGeoTransform(transform) ;

pDriverTiff = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff") ;

pNewDS =  pDriverTiff->Create( output, nCols, nRows, 1, GDT_Int16, NULL) ;
pNewDS->SetGeoTransform(transform) ;
pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->SetNoDataValue(noData) ;

short *oldRow = (short *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(short)*nCols) ;
short *newRow = (short *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(short)*nCols) ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++){
    pOldDS->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, i, nCols, 1, oldRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Int16, 0, 0) ;
    for (int j = 0 ; j < nCols ; j++){
        if (oldRow[j] == noData ){
            newRow[j] = noData ;
            //cout << "nodata : newrow[" << j << "] = " << newrow[j] << endl;
            //system("pause");
        }
        else{
            newRow[j] = oldRow[j] ;
            //cout << "oldrow[" << j << " ]= " << oldRow[j] << endl;
            //cout << "newrow[" << j << " ]= " << newRow[j] << endl;
            //system("pause");
        }
    }
    pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, newRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Int16, 0, 0) ;
    //cout << "newrow= " << &newRow << endl;
}

GDALClose(pOldDS);
GDALClose(pNewDS);

system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious flaws with your code but are you *sure* your input raster is 16 bit? For this type of operation I've used __int16 as 'short' is up to the compiler but guaranteed to be at least 16 bits. A hint: your duplication of oldRow and newRow is wasteful as too are your nested loops, as the array is the same size you could do **pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, oldRow**. I would also suggest casting your band (source and destination) to a GDALRasterBand* object, if only to make less typing.

Comment: Actually, my input raster is byte ( if I call ` GDALGetDataTypeName(poBand->GetRasterDataType()) ` I'll get the "Byte" ) and the value of my raw tiff is 50-233, but if I read the band with 'GDT_Byte', I can't get the right value. I think I misunderstand something, but I directually use the 'GDT_Int16'. 
And back to your suggestion, I check my input raster is 16 bit(if I call `  sizeof(short) ` I'll get the "2"). However, I agree using '__int16' is better, so I changed it, Of cause, all the value of the new image is 128.

Comment: Also, thank your hint, but I tried to calculate the value in three bands and failed. So I tried to  just read and write and still failed. That's why I posted my code to see if I miss somthing.

Answer (score 3):

I just remembered that I had this problem also many years ago, it's in your close statements:

```
GDALClose(pOldDS);
GDALClose(pNewDS);
```

From the [help document](https://gdal.org/api/gdaldataset_cpp.html)

> Equivalent of the C callable GDALClose(). Except that GDALClose()
> first decrements the reference count, and then closes only if it has
> dropped to zero.
> For Windows users, it is not recommended to use the delete operator on
> the dataset object because of known issues when allocating and freeing
> memory across module boundaries. Calling GDALClose() is then a better
> option.

Which means `delete pOldDS;` isn't a safe option so the best way is with `GDALClose`. However the [C callable GDALClose (GDALDatasetH   hDS)](https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALDataset.html#a5d1d8029010ec8de4fe03d3d51ef77c7) expects a parameter of type `GDALDatasetH`, which is different to `GDALDataset*`, so when I changed my close statements to cast the pointer to a handle e.g. `GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)FirstClass_DS);` the dataset was closed properly and flushed to disc. Can you try changing your close statements to:

```
pNewDS->FlushCache(); // only need to flush the dataset that has been written to
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)pOldDS);
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)pNewDS);
GDALDestroyDriverManager(); // this should remove any remaining locks but no more GDAL functions from here will work
```

and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's quite clear. I read the document and I just notice that I shouldn't use 'delete pOldDS;'. I changed my close statements to:
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)pOldDS);
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)pNewDS);
However, all the value of the new image is still 128.

Comment: Perhaps there's still a reference remaining, try flush the writes and GDALDestroyDriverManager(); on the very last line, I'll edit that into the code to show where I put them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the way didn't work. All the value of the new image is still 128. Do you have other idea of that situation?

Comment: The only thing I can see different is I allocate my memory using _aligned_malloc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170 to ensure multibyte types align with the word boundary. As your input raster is of type GDT_Byte perhaps it would be a good time to change the data types to match the input. In the meantime I'll test your code on an 8 bit 3 band raster I have locally.

Comment: I tested your code exactly as written (different raster paths though) with the flush to close and it worked for me. The 16/8 bit data type was not a problem. I'm using 64 bit GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24 with Visual Studio 2012, version 11.0.61219.00 update 5 which is a bit newer than your version of studio, perhaps you might need to grab a much older dev version of GDAL from the archives of GISInternals https://www.gisinternals.com/archive.php.